# Org presentation using "transitions": revealing items?

Tags: org-mode

I want to use `org-mode` for presentations **within emacs**.

There seem to be a couple of libraries for this linked to by:

- https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsPresentation
- http://sachachua.com/blog/2013/04/how-to-present-using-org-mode-in-emacs/

[org-present](https://github.com/rlister/org-present) and [org-presie](https://github.com/nicferrier/org-presie) seem like the candidates, but neither seem to support the delayed revealing of child entries.

## Example

I have an org file like

```
* One
** child1
** child2
* two
** child1
** child2
```

I want to be able to go through displays like

```
* One
```

then

```
* One
** child1
```

then

```
* One
** child1
** child2
```

then

```
* Two
```

then

```
* Two
** Child1
```

then

```
* Two
** Child1
** Child2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can export presentations to html or latex, and present them there. That not only looks better (most of the time), but it's also much simpler to share your deck with non-Emacsen people.

Check out, for example, [org-reveal](https://github.com/yjwen/org-reveal) and [org-beamer](https://github.com/fniessen/refcard-org-beamer). Both of these options allow you to transition and go through displays in the way you want.

If you really want to stick to Emacs and Org Mode, check out the [demo-it](https://github.com/howardabrams/demo-it) package.

Comment: Yep, `beamer` or `reveal` are in a good suggestion for many use cases. It kind of loses emacs street-cred though. I'm sure I could make up some other reasons that emacs might be useful for presentations like demos and such like, but imagine they are really just excuses for "this is cool".

Comment: `demo-it` looks quite nice. It looks like a general purpose automation framework that could be particularly useful for recording screencasts etc.